# How to fix Promise AssertionError with mocha testing for nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, assert

I am new for nodejs programming and mocha testing.

I am trying to create mocha test case with Promise.resolve throwing an Error
but assert.throws not working with it

I have tried function (assert throws)[https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_fn_error_message]

index.js

```
    const reqData = JSON.parse(data);
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            if(reqData){
                throw new Error(
                  'This new error thows!'
                );
            }

            console.log('It works!!');
        })
        .then(() => {
                console.log('work completed');
            }
        )
}
```

index.test.js

```
it('getResult fails without data', async () => {
        const error = new Error(
            'This new error thows!'
        );
        const data = {}
        const err = await assert.throws(
            () => {getResult(data)},
            Error,
            'This new error thows!'
        );
        assert.deepStrictEqual(err, error);
    }
);
```

line await assert.throws giving an error

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing expected exception (Error).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`assert.throws` expects a function that throws an error. This isn't the same thing as rejected promise, which is basically an object.

Another problem is that a function doesn't return `getResult(data)` promise.

The assertion doesn't actually check that the error has `This new error thows!`, instead it results in an error with this message in case it fails.

`assert` in Node 10 and higher [supports promises](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message). It should be:

```
await assert.rejects(
    () => getResult(data),
    {
      constructor: Error,
      message: 'This new error thows!'
    },
    'Promise not rejected'
);
```

Comment: when I try this approach I get a different error: "Uncaught Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ([object Object])"

Comment: I cannot say what cause this error. If you did everything properly, it should work.This could be different case. Consider asking your own question and providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.